# Is there a way to send data from the frontend to the server with an Axios Get request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, psql

I am using React in the front end and Express for the server with PSQL database. I have a component that pulls data so I can display it -

```
  router.get("/conversation", (request, response) => {
    db.query(
      `
        SELECT *
        FROM conversations;
        `,)
      .then(({ rows: messages }) => {
        return response.json(messages);
      });
  });
```

This is my React code -

```
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/messages/conversation")
      .then(
        (response) => {
          setConversations(response.data);
        }
      );

  }, [messages]);
```

There is data that I have in a prop that I'd like to send in my axios get request so I can use it to filter SQL query. I want my query to be something like this -

```
SELECT *
FROM conversations
WHERE receiver_id = props.receiver_id;
```

The props.receiver_id being the data that I want to send

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why not use POST?

Comment: Will a POST work in this scenario? I'm not writing anything to the database, I just want to query it so I can display data on the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL params, such as `axios.get("/messages/conversation?receiver_id=5")` and then the server endpoint can get it with `request.query.receiver_id`.

Comment: I just tried adding ```axios.get(`/messages/conversation?${props.receiver}`)``` and I consoled logged this - ```console.log("Request Query:", request.query);``` and am getting back ```Request Query: { 'object Object': '' }```  

My prop.receiver is an object like so - receiver {id: 1, user_id:3, category: alert}  

Do you know if there is a way to get the entire object in the console log?

Comment: URL query params can't be objects, they must be of form `key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3...`